# How to hide shadowMapEnabler in three.js

Tags: three.js, shadow-mapping, shadows

I have a working code in which shadows are working fine unless and until,
renderer.shadowMapEnabled is set to true. But, the problem here is a shadow map helper is coming in the scene which portrays the movement of direction light from one position to other thus casting a shadow.
I want the shadows to be there but hide the shadow helper.
If I comment renderer.shadowMapEnabled then the shadows don't cast.
Anybody who could help ?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shadows</title>    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/60/three.js"></script>

    <script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShader">

        varying vec3 worldPosition;

        void main() {

            vec4 mPosition = modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
            worldPosition = mPosition.xyz;

        }

    </script>

    <script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentShader">

        uniform vec3 topColor;
        uniform vec3 bottomColor;
        uniform float offset;
        uniform float exponent;

        varying vec3 worldPosition;

        void main() {

            float h = normalize( worldPosition + offset ).y;
            gl_FragColor = vec4( mix( bottomColor, topColor, max( pow( h, exponent ), 0.0 ) ), 1.0 );

        }

    </script>


    <script>
    window.onload = function() {



        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
        //renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        renderer.gammaInput = true;
        renderer.gammaOutput = true;

        renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
        renderer.shadowMapCullFace = THREE.CullFaceBack;


        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var flag = true;

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 30, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000 );
        camera.position.set( -15, 2, 5 );

        camera.lookAt( scene.position );


        // add three objects that cast shadows

        var geometry1 = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 1, 4, 1 );
        var material1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xFF0000 } );
        var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry1, material1 );
        //mesh1.castShadow = true;
        mesh1.receiveShadow = true;
        //scene.add( mesh1 );

        var geometry2 = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 3, 2, 1 );
        var material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x0000FF } );
        var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material2 );
        //mesh2.castShadow = true;
        mesh2.receiveShadow = true;
        mesh2.position.x = 0
        mesh2.position.y = -1.5
        mesh2.position.z = -3
        //scene.add( mesh2 );

        var geometry3 = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 2, 1, 2 );
        var material3 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x00FF00 } );
        var mesh3 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry3, material3 );
        mesh3.position.x = -2
        mesh3.position.y = -2
        mesh3.position.z = -1
        //mesh3.castShadow = true;
        mesh3.receiveShadow = true;
        //scene.add( mesh3 );

        var buildingMesh= new THREE.Mesh(geometry3)
        THREE.GeometryUtils.merge( geometry2, buildingMesh );
        var materialKetan = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xffff00});
        var meshKetan = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2,materialKetan);
        meshKetan.castShadow = true;
        meshKetan.receiveShadow = true;
        meshKetan.position.x = 0;
        meshKetan.position.y = -1.5;
        meshKetan.position.z = -3;

        scene.add(meshKetan);
        // add hemi lights

        var hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0.05 );
        hemiLight.color.setHSL( 0.1, 0.2, 1 );
        hemiLight.groundColor.setHSL( 0.9, 0.2, 1 );
        hemiLight.position.set( 0, 500, 0 );
        scene.add( hemiLight );

        // this is the Sun
        dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
        dirLight.color.setHSL( 0.4, 0.2, 1 );
        dirLight.position.set( -1, 0.75, 1 );
        dirLight.position.multiplyScalar( 50 );
        scene.add( dirLight );
        dirLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;

        dirLight.castShadow = true;
        dirLight.shadowMapWidth = dirLight.shadowMapHeight = 1024*2;

        var d = 5;

        dirLight.shadowCameraLeft = -d;
        dirLight.shadowCameraRight = d;
        dirLight.shadowCameraTop = d;
        dirLight.shadowCameraBottom = -d;

        // the magic is here - this needs to be tweaked if you change dimensions

        dirLight.shadowCameraFar = 20000;
        dirLight.shadowBias = 0.01; //-0.000001
        dirLight.shadowDarkness = 0.09;
        scene.add( dirLight );



        scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0x222233, 0, 20000);
        renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color, 1 );


        // add ground
        var groundGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1000, 1000 );
        var groundMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, specular: 0x050505 } );
        groundMat.color.setHSL( 0.095, 1, 0.75 );
        ground = new THREE.Mesh( groundGeo, groundMat );
        ground.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
        ground.position.y = -2;
        scene.add( ground );
        ground.receiveShadow = true;


        // add skydome

        var vertexShader = document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent;
        var fragmentShader = document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent;
        var uniforms = {
            topColor:    { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0x0077ff ) },
            bottomColor: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0xffffff ) },
            offset:      { type: "f", value: 33 },
            exponent:    { type: "f", value: 0.6 }
        }
        uniforms.topColor.value.copy( hemiLight.color );

        scene.fog.color.copy( uniforms.bottomColor.value );

        var skyGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 4000, 32, 15 );
        var skyMat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { vertexShader: vertexShader, fragmentShader: fragmentShader, uniforms: uniforms, side: THREE.BackSide } );

        var sky = new THREE.Mesh( skyGeo, skyMat );
        scene.add( sky );


        var clock = new THREE.Clock();
        animate();

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            if (flag == true){
               render(); 
            }
        }

        function render() {
            var delta = clock.getDelta();
            renderer.render( scene, camera );


            var time = new Date().getTime() * 0.001;
            //var time = 0.001;

            var nsin = Math.sin(time);
            var ncos = Math.cos(time);

            // set the sun
            dirLight.position.set( 1500*nsin, 2000*nsin, 2000*ncos);



            if (nsin > 0.2 )   // day
            {
                sky.material.uniforms.topColor.value.setRGB(0.25,0.55,1);
                sky.material.uniforms.bottomColor.value.setRGB(1,1,1);
                var f = 1;
                dirLight.intensity = f;
                dirLight.shadowDarkness = f*0.7;
            }

            else if (nsin < 0.2 && nsin > 0.0 )
            {
                var f = nsin/0.2;
                dirLight.intensity = f;
                dirLight.shadowDarkness = f*0.7;

                sky.material.uniforms.topColor.value.setRGB(0.25*f,0.55*f,1*f);
                sky.material.uniforms.bottomColor.value.setRGB(1*f,   1*f,1*f);
            }

            else  // night
            {
                var f = 0;
                dirLight.intensity = f;
                dirLight.shadowDarkness = f*0.7;
                sky.material.uniforms.topColor.value.setRGB(246,134,44);
                sky.material.uniforms.bottomColor.value.setRGB(246,134,44);
            }
        }

    };
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code? Or better yet, a codepen or similar replicating the issue?

Comment: Sure @guardabrazo !

Comment: I have updated the question with a code having similar problem. Please go through it and let me know.

Comment: You are using three.js r.60 which is 4 years old. You will have to update to the current release, update your code, and make a new post if you need help.